# Storing data from a CSV file in 3D table in Oracle Database

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, relational-database, oracle19c

I am trying to automatically fetch data from different CSV files (that are created periodically by another software after every 24 hours) and store into Oracle database. The format of the file is as follows:
[format of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfgw.png)

How should I store this data in an organized manner to properly retrieve that information when required. Date stays the same for one file but changes in every file. I don't know whether I should store this data in a 3D table with reading time the third dimension or use a relationship between actual data and reading time.
I hope I was eloquent enough to make everyone understand my problem.
Regards
ASAD

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific step are you stuck on? "3D table"? Relational databases are two-dimensional, so you can show the content as columns and rows.

Comment: To consider your requirements: append together two files from different days, with different `Reading time`; then (presumably) you'll get repeated `Address`, `Meter serial number`; now explain why `Reading time` is in any way special vs other attributes.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: @AntC I have tried to create a relational model using SQL Data Modeler but could not figure out the relationship between tables or how many tables I need for this particular application. A CSV file similar to the one mentioned in the picture is created after every 24 hour when the power meters read values of the consumed energy, that is why **Reading time** is same for one CSV file and represents a datetime value when the reading was taken.

Comment: @AntC I am trying to create a billing software for the energy consumed by each tenet on daily, weekly and monthly basis. I need to store this energy data in Oracle database every time the CSV file is generated. Thanks

Comment: Oh dear. Firstly, there are plenty of off-the-shelf billing applications for metering. They cover situations you appear not yet to have anticipated -- like corrections to previous readings/re-billing; changing/replacing a meter and re-calibrating. I strongly recommend _not_ trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Secondly, you seem to be obsessed with a 'daily dump' of readings. This is not realistic: you might go for several days without getting a file; you might get several files at times through the day; a file might get corrupted in transit, and you need to re-load or just ignore some download.

Comment: Thirdly, you seem to have no idea about schema design, functional dependencies or normalisation. You need to read a basic textbook. StackOverflow is not the place to ask these beginner's questions that are amply covered elsewhere.